# Función 'canActivate' de los 'routes guards'

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo una aplicación dónde el usuario tenga que iniciar sesión para poder acceder a las demás rutas, en el caso de que no pueda acceder a su cuenta, no le dejaría navegar y se quedaría siempre en la página de inicio de sesión.

El problema aparece cuando el usuario accede a su cuenta de forma correcta y debería permitir navegar por toda la aplicación, pero de alguna manera cuando hace uso de la función `canActivate` la variable boolean que utilizo para controlar si es correcto o no, los datos introducidos por el usuario, se resetea.

**auth.service.ts**

```
login(name: string, password: string): boolean {
  if (!name && !password) { return; }
  for (let x = 0; x < this.logArray.length; x++) {
    if (name === this.logArray[x].name && password === this.logArray[x].password) {
      return this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
canActivate(): boolean {
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './log/log.module#LogModule' },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
];
```

**Explicación**

En el archivo `auth.service.ts` compruebo los datos introducidos por el usuario y si están correctos, establezco la variable `isLoggedIn` a `true`, para más tarde, en el archivo `auth-guard.service.ts` compruebe el valor de la variable `isLoggedIn` pero **siempre** lo detecta como `false`.

Lo que tengo de código es demasiado simple y no sé dónde puede estar reseteando el valor de variable.

Comment: Por un *breakpoint* donde tengas `this.isLoggendIn=false` y mira si alguien lo llama, con el código que has puesto no se puede reproducir el error.

Comment: Lo he comprobado y lo detecta como false. Como si se tratase de otra aplicación a parte. Dónde único toco el valor de la variable es en el código que he mostrado.

Comment: *lo detecta como false*... ¿Has comprobado si realmente es false? No undefined o null

Comment: Lo declaro e inicializo como false, además tengo un console.log justo antes de permitir o denegar el acceso a las rutas y siempre me sale false. Pongo a proposito el valor de la variable a true (donde quiero que esté para que me funcione la aplicación) y funciona como debería. Únicamente me falla que no está pasando el valor correctamente.

Comment: ¿Cómo inyectas el servicio en el guard? Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas otra instancia del servicio funcionando que no esté inicializada a true

Comment: Lo único que hago es importar `auth.service.ts` en `auth-guard.service.ts` para poder obtener el valor de la variable. Lo que no se si tiene algo que ver, pero tengo un módulo con su propio routing de `log` y con eso se crea otra instancia sin que yo lo sepa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucioné el error que tenía.

Simplemente tenia un componente con su módulo completo, trabajaba con las variables en un servicio ajeno a ese directorio y por ello, reconocía como si fuera otra estancia, básicamente utilicé el propio servicio que se encontraba dentro del módulo, en mi caso es `log.service.ts`, en este archivo establezco los mismos procedimientos que sigo en el archivo `auth.service.ts` que tengo en la pregunta. Espero que le sirva de ayuda a otros que tengan el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

que bueno que encontraran la solución amigo, igual ojo como se vuelve a cargar la página algunos datos se pueden perder si se vuelve a cargar con this.router.navigate. por eso en ves de ocupar variables en el services utilice localstorage:

función login:

```js
let params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: { email: usuario.email, password: usuario.password },
    });
    
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
    };

    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/usuario/login`, params.toString(), httpOptions).pipe(
      map(
        (resp) => {
          //sab
          this.guardarToken(resp['data'], resp['accessToken']);
          return resp;
        },
        (error) => {
          return error;
        }
      )
    );
```

función guardarToken:

```js
 //sab
    this.userToken$.emit(true);
    localStorage.setItem('id', tokenBack['id']);
    localStorage.setItem('email', tokenBack['email']);
    localStorage.setItem('role', tokenBack['role']);
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
    let hoy = new Date();
    hoy.setSeconds(3600);

    localStorage.setItem('expira', hoy.getTime().toString());
```

ahora utilizando los metodos get se puede obtener fácilmente la información para los guards.